# How to trigger compile & reload in a cljs figwheel and cljsbuild project on webpack bundle update?

Tags: webpack, clojurescript, figwheel, cljsbuild

I have a mostly cljs project which I'd like to have figwheel compile and reload whenever I change the bundle.js file generated by webpack. I have webpack regenerating bundle.js whenever I edit the js, but how do I get figwheel to notice that its changed?  I feel I need something like the :css-dirs option, but for js, not css.

cljsbuild probably needs to be triggered too. I do have a :foreign-libs declaration in my compilation options that references the webpack bundle, but this may not be enough.